# web2py, URL() error when dynamically serving static files

Tags: url, static, web2py

I am generating static files on the fly but cannot get the URL function to work:
NB: here `filename` is a key-value returned by the controller

```
{{=P(A('Download ', filename,_href=URL('static', filename)))}}
```

generates an error:

```
type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> when calling URL, function or function name required
```

However if I replace the filename variable with a string (as follows) the link is generated OK

```
{{=P(A('Download ', filename,_href=URL('static', 'abcis_data_42Data_.NO2.__.zip')))}}
```

Any ideas?

---

**OK solved.**  *filename is of type unicode and using str(filename) solves the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might have to do here is go down the MVC hierarchy, so your code might look like:

```
{{=P(A('Download',filename,_href=URL(r=request,c='static',f=filename)))}}
```